# SQL Query Optimizations for conditions

Tags: mysql

I am learning SQL.

I tried to fetch the record from database and I archived it successfull what I wanted,

here is my Query:

```
select
  CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'Accounts Receivable' ELSE 'Accounts Payable' End as Account,
  BUILTIN.DF(t.Entity) as Name,
  BUILTIN.DF(tl.subsidiary) as Subsidiary,
  t.Tranid AS " + trannoalias + ",
  t.TranDate as " + datealias + ",
  CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'BILL' THEN 'BILL' WHEN t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'INVOICE' ELSE 'BILL PAYMENT' End as " + trantypealias +",
  ap.periodname AS " + periodalias + ",
  CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
  AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
  AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END as " + sourceexchangeratealias + ",
  cr2.Exchangerate as " + endingexchangeratealias + ",
  BUILTIN.DF(t.currency) as " + currencyalias +",
  Round(ForeignTotal, 2) as " + currencybalancealias + ",
  Round(
    (
      (
        cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
        AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
        AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END
      ) * ForeignTotal
    ),
    2
  ) AS " + netgainalias + ",
  cexr.averagerate as " + consolidatedexchangerate + ",
  Round(
    (
      (
        cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
        AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
        AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END
      ) * (ForeignTotal * cexr.averagerate)
    ),
    2
  ) AS " + consolidatedgain + "
from
  Transaction t
  INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl ON (tl.Transaction = t.ID)
  INNER JOIN Subsidiary sb ON sb.id = tl.subsidiary
  INNER JOIN AccountingPeriod ap ON (
    (
      ap.id BETWEEN (" + periodFromId + ")
      AND (" + periodToId + ")
    )
    AND ap.isposting = 'T'
  )
  INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr1 ON (
    cr1.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
    AND cr1.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
    AND (
      cr1.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    )
  )
  INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr2 ON (
    cr2.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
    AND cr2.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
    AND (
      cr2.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    )
  )
  LEFT JOIN CurrencyRate cr3 ON (
    cr3.BaseCurrency = "+basecurrency+"
    AND cr3.TransactionCurrency = sb.currency
    AND (
      cr3.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(t.TranDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    )
  )
  INNER JOIN consolidatedexchangerate cexr ON (
    cexr.postingperiod = t.PostingPeriod
    AND cexr.fromsubsidiary = tl.subsidiary
    AND cexr.tosubsidiary = 1
  )
Where
  (
    (
      t.AbbrevType = ('BILL')
      AND BUILTIN.DF(t.Status) = ('Bill : Open')
    )
    OR t.AbbrevType = ('BILLPMT')
    OR (
      t.AbbrevType = ('INV')
      AND BUILTIN.DF(t.Status) = ('Invoice : Open')
    )
  )
  AND (tl.MainLine = 'T')
  AND (tl.subsidiary IN (" + subsidiaryId + "))
```

The the condition takes to much time to load data.

I tried to optimize it by changing it to "IN" instead of AND in were section, but the result returns empty.

Is there any alternate way to optimize it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `BUILTIN.DF`?

Re `cr2.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`, it is usually better to store dates in `DATE` format, converting only when displaying.

`OR` is a performance killer.  However, it may not be practical to switch to a `UNION`.  Still, adding this to the `WHERE` *may* help: `AND t.AbbrevType in ('BILL', 'BILLPMT', 'INV')`

These indexes may help:

```
tl: INDEX(MainLine, subsidiary, Transaction)
cexr:  (tosubsidiary, fromsubsidiary, postingperiod, averagerate)
CurrencyRate:  (TransactionCurrency, EffectiveDate, BaseCurrency, Exchangerate)
sb:  (currency, id)
ap:  (isposting, id, enddate, startdate, periodname)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an ambitious query for someone learning SQL!

I would start by reviewing the indexes on the columns that are part of your joins and where clause.

A technique that has helped me is to review the query plan. If you are using MySQL, you can check this out by adjusting the beginning of your query like:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE CASE ...
```

The query plan will show you approximate row counts and indexes that are being used when the query runs. That may help guide you toward identifying instances where table indexes are not being incorporated as you might hope.